# What is the purpose of css-loader in webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, sass, webpack

I'm starting to work with Webpack 2 and I saw that a lot of projects are using the css-loader and I didn't find what is the purpose for it.

Comment: Did you read the readme.md? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

Comment: Yes but I didn't found it helpful

Comment: Maybe expand your question with what parts are confusing?

Comment: Webpack can bundle styles as well as javascript.  css-loader allows you to import *.css in your bundle.  Webpack will walk down the `@import` and `url()` in the css as well.

Comment: Why I will want to use it? for example I understand whey I would use sass-loader it will create css from scss files

Comment: after sass is compiled to css (with sass-loader), css loader bundles AFAIK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

**EDIT: In original answer I was describing `style-loader` not `css-loader`. It's easy to forget different purpose of those loader since `css-loader` can only be used with `style-loader`.**

---

## New answer

`css-loader` gives you more control over importing `.css` files.

**1. Transforms `url(image.png) => require('./image.png')`**

Since now `require` is used, it's enables you to use for example `file-loader` or `url-loader`.
Now `url(image.png)` can be converted to:

```
url(/public-path/0dcbbaa701328a3c262cfd45869e351f.png)
```

or with limit property of `url-loader` creates inline picture:

```
url(data:image/jpeg;base64,LzlqLzRBQ ... zdF3)
```

**2. Enables [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)**

Let's consider styles of `componentA` and `componentB`:

`componentA/style.css`

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
}
.specificToComponentA {
  // rest of styles
}
```

`componentB/style.css`

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
}
.specificToComponentB {
  // rest of styles
}
```

`componentA` looks:

```
import './style.css';

export default function () {
  document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="specificToComponentA">componentA</div>
    </div>
  `;
}
```

and `componentB` looks:

```
import './style.css';

export default function () {
  document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="specificToComponentB">componentB</div>
    </div>
  `;
}
```

What color of background color those components would have? This problem is related with leaking of styles, it's hard to tell if they are will be red or blue (it's hard to predict order of styles created by `style-loader`). If you use CSS Modules approach you can deal with this problem.
Now import styles to variable and this variable will contain object with mapping class names:

`componentA` with CSS Modules looks:

```
import s from './style.css';

export default function () {
  document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="${s.wrapper}">
      <div class="${s.specificToComponentA}">componentA</div>
    </div>
  `;
}
```

`s` object will contain :

```
{
  wrapper: "WO0HHIhH77",
  specificToComponentA: "jPYPsVTDZu"
}
```

`componentA/style.css` will be converted to

```
.WO0HHIhH77 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.jPYPsVTDZu {
  // rest of styles
}
```

and `componentB` with CSS Modules looks:

```
import s from './style.css';

export default function () {
  document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="${s.wrapper}">
      <div class="${s.specificToComponentB}">componentB</div>
    </div>
  `;
}
```

`s` object will contain :

```
{
  wrapper: "C8EKTwiZfd", // Look, different than in componentA!!!
  specificToComponentB: "KI5jRsC2R5"
}
```

`componentB/style.css` will be converted to

```
.C8EKTwiZfd { // Look, different than in componentA!!!
  background-color: red;
}
.KI5jRsC2R5 {
  // rest of styles
}
```

And now even if you don't use super specific name like `wrapper` in both components you are sure that they don't overlap and `componentA` stays blue and `componentB` red. It's great power of encapsulation of styles described as CSS Modules - it is possible with help of `css-loader`.

## OldAnswer

#### <s>css-loader</s> style-loader change couples js and css

Let's consider this structure of project

```
├── components 
│   │
│   ├── componentA
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   └── index.js
│   │
│   ├── componentB
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   └── index.js
│   │
│   └── componentC
│       ├── style.css
│       └── index.js
│   
├── index.js  
└── index.html
```

`index.js` looks like this

```
import componentA from './components/componentA';
import componentB from './components/componentB';
import componentC from './components/componentC';

componentA();
componentB();
componentC();
```

**1. Without <s>css-loader</s> style-loader**

each of `*.js` components in general looks like this

```
export default function () {
  // logic of this component
}
```

`index.html` contains

```
<link href="components/componentA/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="components/componentB/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="components/componentC/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Now if you want to refactor your code and for example disable `componentB` you must remove it from `index.js`

```
import componentA from './components/componentA';
// import componentB from './components/componentB';
import componentC from './components/componentC';

componentA();
// componentB();
componentC();
```

and since css and js are decoupled you must do the same for styles in `index.html`

```
<link href="components/componentA/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- <link href="components/componentB/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
<link href="components/componentC/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

This duplication in large project can lead to leaving dead css code - it's harder to maintain since you must do two things in separate places.

**NOTE:** SASS or LESS have the same problem. It's only moved from `index.html` to `index.sass`:

```
@import './components/componentA';
@import './components/componentB'; // you must disable this manually
@import './components/componentC';
```

**2. With <s>css-loader</s> style-loader**

Now you point to styles related to some component directly from it (not in separate place like in 1. point)
For example your `*.js` component will look like

```
import './style.css';

export default function () {
  // logic of this component
}
```

and `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

The most important is that if you have this architecture and want to disable `componentB`, only what you do is

```
import componentA from './components/componentA';
// import componentB from './components/componentB';
import componentC from './components/componentC';

componentA();
// componentB();
componentC();
```

It's all! No more looking for reference of styles `componentB/style.css` in any `.html` or `.sass` or `.less`. The same goes if you want to add new components: by simply importing `.js` file you add js logic and css styles. This is much easier to maintain!

Comment: Thanks for great answer. it help me to really understandץ

Comment: @ofirfridman sorry for misleading but I confused css-modules with style-loader. Now I had to describe both.

Comment: You mentioned that css-loader will interpret @import as require. Does that mean webpack will take over the resolving for that file? (Sounds recursive to me, but I want to verify). I want to believe this but then i saw the "importLoaders" option in css-loader, which is perplexing because if Webpack just takes over, this option would not be necessary?

Comment: @prk_001 I think you answer yourself. The most probably in your scenario webpack is an overkill.

Comment: @Everettss thanks, this is what I thought. I know that Webpack is mostly for JS apps, in my case then Grunt or Gulp would be enough. It makes sense, cause setting up Webpack just for styles compilation seems way too much hassle.

Answer (score 4):

In `.js` file **ES6** `import` or **CommonJS**'s `require()` allows you to import only JavaScript files(modules) into it. So when you include your `styles.css`, for instance, in `.js` file via `import from './styles.css'`, you'll need to convert in into `.js` in the first place. And here is where **css-loader** comes to the rescue.